# How to make the text of UITextField to appear with First letter Capital in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I have a text box and I am  only interested in capitalizing the first letter, So how to do that in iPhone UITextField.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

try this:

```
tf = [[UITextField alloc] init];
tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
```

or set this property in the properties inspector in Interface Builder

Answer (score 47):

**Swift 3 :**

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
textField.autocapitalizationType = .words
textField.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
```

Output :

- **Sentences** : This is text input.
- **Words** : This Is Text Input.
- **All characters** : THIS IS TEXT INPUT.

Answer (score 22):

In the *Attributes Inspector*, near the bottom of the Text Field section, there is a setting called `Capitalization` with a drop down menu.  Here, you can select `Words`, `Sentences`, or `All Characters`.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the Attributes Inspector , there is a  Capitalization with a drop down menu. Here, you can select Words, Sentences, or All Characters.

- **Word** : if you select  Word than first character of every word is
  Capital
- **Sentences** : if you Sentence  than first character of First word of
  every sentence  is Capital
- **All Characters** : All Characters are Capital

Answer (score 4):

Swift:

```
tf.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
```

Answer (score 3):

Select your text field ,go in interface builder(properties option) storyboard there is a option Capatalization set it to sentence.enjoy!!!